# Переменные в методах

Tags: java

Заранее прошу простить за, наверняка, глупый вопрос! Как мне использовать переменные одного метода в другом внутри класса? Скажем один находит nное число, а в другом методе с этим числом надобно что то еще сотворить. Заранее благодарен. Сильно не пинайте)

Comment: пусть первый возвратит найденное число, другой же посредством вызова первого его получит и "сотворит" с ним все, что нужно :)

Comment: премного благодарен))

Answer (score 2):

Использование локальных переменных одного метода в другом не только невозможно*, но и не нужно. Пусть один метод возвращает наружу всё, что может быть интересно (либо как return-значение, либо сохраняет в полях класса), а другой метод сможет работать с этим значением (либо как аргумент, либо из поля класса).

Решение о том, передавать ли значения через возврат из функции или поля класса, принимайте сообразно семантике (то есть, смыслу) класса. Например, если у вас есть класс `Автомобиль`, то поле `ТекущаяСкорость` имеет смысл, а вот поле `СуммаКвадратовЭлементовКакогоТоМассива` наверное нет.

---

*Да, ещё есть лямбды в Java 8

Answer (score -2):

```
public class heshCode {
    private static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Counter();
        System.out.println(count); // сотворили 
    }

    private static void Counter(){
        count++; // нашли число
    }
}
```

Comment: и че эт такое?

Comment: походу такое даже не скоптилируется

Comment: а вы рискнете и попробуйте

Comment: @sonniy то есть Вы предлагаете все что нужно будет менять в нескольких методах выносить как static поля (ну или вообще поля класса), если честно вообще трудно уловить что Вы этим хотели показать